# Firebase renders every document inside a collection

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have this Firebase-database, in which I, as collections store the different continents. Each continent has a document which is a review. Each document holds some information that I want to display when the user selects a document.

My problem is, whenever I query some data from Firebase, everything that is held by the collection renders.

Let me show you a picture:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/hC4f3.jpg

The first picture is my database,
The second picture is when I query something.

Now, I'm not sure if this is because of my Firebase-query code or if it's something else. I've picked my brain for a couple of days but I cannot get anywhere.

This is how I query:

```
const useCountries = (continent) => {
    const [countries, setCountries] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log(continent)
        firebase
            .firestore()
            .collection(continent)
            .onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
                const newCountries = snapshot.docs.map((doc) => ({
                    id: doc.id,
                    ...doc.data()

                }))
                setCountries(newCountries)

            })

    }, [])
    return countries
}
```

I am fairly sure that the problem lies within this block of code. Could that be it? I think the problem is something with the snapshot, always listening for new stuff and essentially renders everything.

So, what would I like to show?

Ok, so this is a review site. I use a vertical navbar to display each continent and then, a new navbar that shows the name of the review. The name of the reviews are also the name of the document.

This piece of code is part of the component that holds the names:

```
const CountryList = ({ continent, displayFields = [] }) => {
    const countries = useCountries(continent, revName);
 ...

    return (
        <div className="countries">
            {countries.map(country => (
                <div key={country.id}>
                    <div className="entry">

                        {displayFields.includes("dest1") && (
                            <div>Destination 1: {country.dest1}
                            </div>
                        )}
                        {displayFields.includes("continent") && (
                            <div>{country.continent}</div>
                        )}
                        {displayFields.includes("revName") && (
                            <div>{country.revName}</div>
                        )}
```

And it's the revName that I'd like to use to query.

I hope that I've explained myself, at least good enough.

Edit:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/visoZ.jpg
This is the vertical navbar, which uses the continents. I populate this navbar using:

```
 <Menu className="nav-icon">
    <CountryList
      continent={props.continent}
      displayFields={["countryName"]}
    />
  </Menu>
```

Basically, I call the useCountries-hook to crate an array of the continents to display here.

Thank!

Comment: what I can see from code is you are mapping over the snapshot and saving all into a new array called newCountries. If you need specific review to be displayed then pass that in hook and use that in map to filter out the one needed

Comment: The thing is, that I use this array to display every continent aswell. If I mess with it, the other components that are depending on this one will blow, I think. But I'll take your suggestion into consideration and play with it. Could I perhaps add one other hook in some way? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, it is better to keep different hooks for different functionality. Can you also provide how useCountries hook is used for displaying continent?

Comment: Done, edited my main post. Please, I'm very new to this as you might understand. Your solution probably doesn't even have an impact on my displaying continents. Thanks for answering my questions.

Comment: If you want to get more help with working out the solution, you can put code on online-editor like codesandbox, we can collaborate over there

Comment: Sure! However, I'm not sure what I should add to it. Only the relevant files? Though that wouldn't work. Everything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is add the conditional to check if it the selected one or not and based on that show correct review.

```
{countries.map(country => (
                <div key={country.id}>
                    <div className="entry">

                        {displayFields.includes("dest1") && country.dest1 === currentCity && (
                            <div>Destination 1: {country.dest1}
                            </div>
                        )}
                        {displayFields.includes("continent") && (
                            <div>{country.continent}</div>
                        )}
                        {displayFields.includes("revName") && country.dest1 === currentCity &&(
                            <div>{country.revName}</div>
                        )}
```

where currentCity would be the one selected

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Thanks alot!